# Get the SSL certificate of client using netty

Tags: java, ssl, netty

I have the following code, which is used to get the client ssl certificate ,but it looks like `getPeerCertificateChain()` is depreciated is there any other way to get client certificate using netty.

```
        `sslengine.getSession().getPeerCertificateChain()`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
sslEngine.getSession().getPeerCertificates()
```